Langchain unpredicted behavior create_sql_query_chain
I am new to Langchain and I try to currently wrap my head around a tutorial to build a LLM Agent to interact with a SQL data base (https://python.langchain.com/v0.2/docs/tutorials/sql_qa/).
I am running into issues early on. When I run the code, the create_sql_query_chain always produces a different output than expected. In the provided link, the following code snippet is supposed to result a variable 'response' containing a pure SQL query which is runnable using for example db.run(response)
import getpass
import os

if not os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY"):
    os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = getpass.getpass()

# Comment out the below to opt-out of using LangSmith in this notebook. Not required.
if not os.environ.get("LANGCHAIN_API_KEY"):
    os.environ["LANGCHAIN_API_KEY"] = getpass.getpass()
    os.environ["LANGCHAIN_TRACING_V2"] = "true"

from langchain_community.utilities import SQLDatabase

db = SQLDatabase.from_uri("sqlite:///Chinook.db")
print(db.dialect)
print(db.get_usable_table_names())
db.run("SELECT * FROM Artist LIMIT 10;")

import getpass
import os

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = getpass.getpass()

from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI

llm = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-4o-mini")

from langchain.chains import create_sql_query_chain

chain = create_sql_query_chain(llm, db)
response = chain.invoke({"question": "How many employees are there"})
response

Yet in my case, it results in a response containing more junk:
'sql\nSQLQuery: SELECT COUNT("EmployeeId") AS "EmployeeCount" FROM "Employee";\n\n\n```sql'
This behavior renders the function langchain.chains.create_sql_query_chain unusable without further processing.
I have a hard time figuring out, how to create a prompt which leads to the desired output only containing a SQL query. I looked probably 10 other tutorials covering the same topic. In each of them I run into the same issue.
I tried different models and coming up with my own prompt, which did not solve the problem at hand. I tried it locally with Ollama and LLama3.1 such LLama3.1 using the Groq to get faster results.

this works for me well:
1. create some variables if needed and examples of queries:
table_info = list(['emp_table'])  
top_k = 10   

examples = [
        { "input": "top 10 employees", "query": "select top 10 emp from emp_table", }, 
..
]

2. then create examples prompt
example_prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template( "Questions: {input}\nSQL query: {query}" )

3. create template:
mssql_prompt = FewShotPromptTemplate( 
        examples = examples, 
        example_prompt = example_prompt, 
        prefix = "Given an input question, first create a syntactically correct mssql query to run, then look at the results of the query and return the answer. Only return SQL Query not anything else like ```sql ... ```. Unless the user specifies in his question a specific number of examples he wishes to obtain, always limit your query to at most {top_k} results. Never query for all the columns from a specific table; only ask for the few relevant columns given the question. Pay attention to use only the column names that you can see in the schema description. Be careful not to query for columns that do not exist. Also, pay attention to which column is in which table. \n\n Only use the following tables: \n {table_info}\n Question: {input}",
        
        suffix = "User Question: {input}\n SQL query: ", 
        input_variables = ["input", "top_k", "table_info"], 
       
) 

4. Compose a chain
write_query = create_sql_query_chain(llm, db, prompt = mssql_prompt, k = top_k)

5. Invoke SQL generation
query = write_query.invoke({"question": input})

6. Follow the guide
here from "Execute SQL query" and on and you should be fine

I had the same issue, it looks like in recent updates Langchain added this ```sql...``` pattern to the create_sql_query_chain prompt.
So I updated the prompt template:
from langchain_core.output_parsers import StrOutputParser
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate

system = """Double check the user's {dialect} query for common mistakes, including:
- Only return SQL Query not anything else like ```sql ... ```
- Using NOT IN with NULL values
- Using UNION when UNION ALL should have been used
- Using BETWEEN for exclusive ranges
- Data type mismatch in predicates\
- Using the correct number of arguments for functions
- Casting to the correct data type
- Using the proper columns for joins

If there are any of the above mistakes, rewrite the query.
If there are no mistakes, just reproduce the original query with no further commentary.

Output the final SQL query only."""

prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
    [("system", system), ("human", "{query}")]
).partial(dialect=db.dialect)
validation_chain = prompt | llm | StrOutputParser()

full_chain = {"query": chain} | validation_chain

Then it generates the correct prompt for me:
query = full_chain.invoke(
    {
        "question": "WWho is the fastest driver?"
    }
)
print(query)

db.run(query)


You can try writing a custom python code to fix the sql query:
def fix_sql_query(ai_message: str) -> str:
    prefix_length = len("SQLQuery: ")
    start_index = ai_message.index("SQLQuery: ")
    fixed = ai_message[start_index + prefix_length:]
    return fixed


write_query = create_sql_query_chain(llm, db)
chain = write_query | fix_sql_query
result = chain.invoke({"question": "How many employees are there"})

